# XSLT: convert a single element's attribute to a new element

Tags: xml, xslt

Basically I want to take the attribute of only one specific element (`category`) and create a new child element (`categoryid`) with the attribute value converted to an element value.

I want to convert this...

```
<root>
  <category id="123">
    <something id="777">987</something>
    <nothing>555</nothing>
  </category>
</root>
```

to this...

```
<root>
  <category>
    <categoryid>123</categoryid>
    <something id="777">987</something>
    <nothing>555</nothing>
  </category>
</root>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with an [identity transform](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#copying) and add a template to match the attribute you want to convert to an element...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="category/@id">
    <categoryid>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </categoryid>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaFa

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="category">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:element name="categoryid">
                <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="something">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="nothing">
        <xsl:element name="nothing">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
```